# Cannot understand the effect of changing variable positions in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am fairly new to coding and I am currently learning Javascript. I had this one problem while taking introductory course on CodeCademy.

My line of code looks something like this:

```js
var text = "fewij 9wieopfjerogjerpjf pweijgroireois joerjgoano hnopahf[gjhr0fgjharobihroephg h8h 8pgh8aphvp oehar9tgh034jh f0sheg9h34up hvszoph f9puwahothoishgp34h98p h40thwoipnoi Roman e0jf0erhjg0pehr08gh038htg0a8whje08h430q8ghgv0ejr0v8g34jh098rtju209ghj98dhb98h 8948he088h sdhg9u nu3iqn 9ahs89h";

var myName = "Roman";

var hits = [];

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === "R") {
    for (i = a; a < (i + myName.length); a++) {
      hits.push(text[a]);
    }
  }
}
if (hits === 0) {
  console.log("Your name was not found.");
} else {
  console.log(hits);
}
```

Basically the program is designed to search my name from the jumble of text and then printing out my name in individual letters in form of an array. Like so ['R', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'n']. However, I could not understand why changing the position of variables "a" and "i" in second for loop produces very different results.

If I typed the second for loop like so:

```
for(a = i; a < (i+myName.length); a++){
     hits.push(text[a]);
}
```

it would yield an array that would not contain the letters from my name. On each run it would put together a random sequence of letters from var text.

Why defining a starting point for second for loop in another order makes the program behave in such different way? Shouldn't it follow the basic mathematical logic like:

```
i=30; //suppose first letter of my name in var text appears to have this array index
i=a; //now I define a new variable 
a=30; //so the new variable should have the same array index as variable i
```

I cannot wrap my mind around it.

Comment: Not sure I get it, but you're not creating a *new* `i` in the inner loop, you're just changing the value of the `i` from the outer loop.

Comment: You need to go back to the tutorial and learn the difference between `i = a` and `a = i`.

Comment: Where do you define `a` in your code?

Comment: `if(hits === 0)` will never succeed. `hits` is an array, `0` is a number, they can never be equal. I suspect you meant `if (hits.length === 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assignment has a direction -- the value on the right is put into the variable on the left. So

```
i = a
```

means take the value of the variable `a`, and put it into the variable `i`.

In your code, the variable `a` was never given a value before the second loop, so `i = a` gets an error.

Changing it to

```
a = i
```

makes it work because `i` was given a value in the first loop, and this copies that value to the `a` variable.

Comment: Thanks! That was the kind of answer I was looking for. Will keep this assignment direction in mind for future uses.

Comment: FYI, it's similar in just about any programming language you're likely to use. And I'm surprised it's not explained in the tutorial you're learning from.